# AVL tree visualization c#

Tags: c#

I have a school project to implement an AVL Tree and to do some kind of UI application to show how it works. I haven't done the code of the implementation yet, but that is not the trouble. I have no idea how to visualize my implementation. I want to do something like this: http://visualgo.net/bst.html# . Could somebody give me some directions about?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. I'll give you a few sulutions that seems to be easy to implement:

1. Write a simple WinForms applications with only one window. This window should contain only one control i.e. [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx). You should populate it by recursively traversing your AVL tree and adding [TreeNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode(v=vs.110).aspx) to it. It is simple and quick solution. The disadvantage is that the final result will not be like in your example.
2. You will get a similar effect if you use  WPF technology and its [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TreeViewItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.
3. The result similar to your example should be achieved with [Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout](https://github.com/Microsoft/automatic-graph-layout). I used it quite intensively and I can recommend it. It is also not difficult in use.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use WPF. You create a Tree obvject that you bind to a hierarchical control.

As soon as you add items to the tree the UI will update. I would suggest it always over Winforms. Do yourself a favour and do not use them